# Is MVC is only for web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create an application which i want to work both on web and windows for which i want to make seperate presentation layer. first of all i want to know, Is MVC is only for web applications?

Comment: There is a difference between [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) (a framework for web applications) and the [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which is a more general pattern that can be used for just about any UI.

Comment: Also ASP.Net MVC includes some sub libraries which are really quite good outside of the web, such as the Razor Templating engine.

Answer (score 2):

By all means no.   Check out this quote from http://blog.iandavis.com/2008/12/09/what-are-the-benefits-of-mvc/

> The Model/View/Controller (MVC) triad of classes [first described by
>   Krasner and Pope in 1988] is used to build user interfaces in
>   Smalltalk-80.

When I was in graduate school we used MVC for Java apps...

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily only for web, depends on how you use it. It's just a framework that should work on both. Example, iOS development is also done on MVC style. But if you're using `WPF/Silverlight`, you should look at `MVVM` rather than `MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know MVC gives you more command over building the html. User MVC if you want a clean and more controlled html output. if you are developing a business application set-up a a solution and DAL and other business logics layers in class library type projects and then build separate user interfaces for both web and desktop. ASP.NET will be best if you don't want more control over output HTML.